# What is the inverse of a random matrix with non-zero diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a large random matrix $A$ with $d$ as the diagonal elements and off-diagonal elements are sampled i.i.d from $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$, $\sigma\leq d\sqrt{S}$, where $S$ is the matrix dimension. I'm interested in the general form of the inverse. Here's what I've found out so far (part of these insights are based on numerical simulations).

1. The diagonal entries of $A^{-1}$ are essentially $1/d$
2. The off diagonal entries appear to be i.i.d. with mean 0 but unknown variance (and variance depends on $S$).
3. By the circular law we know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are a circle centered at $-d$ with radius $r = \sigma\sqrt{S}$. I can prove that the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are in a circle centered at $-d/(d^2-r^2)$ with radius $r/(d^2-r^2)$, but they are not uniformly distributed within this circle.

Obviously, 1 and 2 contradict 3, because otherwise the circle would be centered at $-1/d$. Most likely, the off-diagonal entries are not i.i.d. but merely have 0 correlation.
Additionally, the variance of the off-diagonal entries is not given by $\sigma/(d^2-r^2)$, as suggested by the radius of the circle (based on numerical computations).